# Setting the value of an input field without refreshing the page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to use AJAX to auto complete the users text. Right now I got AJAX to return the results I need for the auto complete feature to the 'suggestions' div as the user types. However, what I am trying to accomplish is a dropdown coming out of the input field ("prod-name") with suggestions as options where the user can simply click on their preferred suggestion and make it the 'value' of the input (similar to how google has search suggestions as you type, but a simplified version).

My markup sof far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function search(searchword) {
      $('#suggestion').load('invoice-get-data.php?searchword=' + searchword);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="prod-name">
    <input onKeyPress="search(this.value)" type="text" id="prod-name"/>
    <div id="suggestion"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

My AJAX code so far (invoice-get-data.php code snippet)

```
$searchword = $_GET['searchword'];

    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_name LIKE '".$searchword."%'") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        echo $row['prod-name'] . '<br>';
    }
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). As it stands, your code is open to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll keep that in mind. However, I am currently using a testing server and SQL injection shouldn't prevent me from running the script successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery ui provides a widget for such autocompletion : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ .

The javascript side would be:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#prod-name" ).autocomplete({
        source: "invoice-get-data.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            alert("Product #" + ui.item.id + " selected");
            return true;
        }
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

And the PHP side would be:

```
$searchword = $_GET['term'];

$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_name LIKE '".$searchword."%'") or die(mysql_error());

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    $data[]     = array(
        "id"        => $row['id'],
        "value"     => $row['prod-name'],
        "label"     => $row['prod-name']
    );
}   

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I appreciate it. I don't understand how I can collect the php array data in the javascript function to set source in the jquery autocomplete code: to the values in $data array? ... I am trying to use the method in the manual link you included which sets the 'source' value to an array obj.

Comment: In the 'select' event, the object ui.item contains the values of $data array (id, value, label, or any index you add in $data)